# Sqoop compatibility with TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

For a project of mine, I would like to transfer multiple tables fomr a MySQL database into hive using sqoop. Because I have a few columns that use the MEDIUMTEXT datatype, I'd like to check the compatibility with someone that has experience, to prevent sudden surprises down the road.

Taken from the latest [Sqoop userguide (1.4.6)](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_blob_literal_and_literal_clob_literal_columns) there is no compatibility for BLOB, CLOB, or LONGVARBINARY columns in direct mode.

Given that there is no mention of incompatibilities with "TEXT" datatypes, will I be able to import them from MySQL without problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around to setting up my hadoop cluster for my project. I am using hadoop 2.6.3 with hive 1.2.1 and sqoop 1.4.6.
It turns out that there is no problem with importing TEXT datatypes from MySQL into Hive using Sqoop. You can even supply the '--direct' parameter that makes use of the mysqldump tool for quicker transfers. In my project I had to import multiple tables containing 2 MEDIUMTEXT columns each. The tables were only about 2 GB each, so not that massive.

I hope this helps someone that is in the same sitation I was in.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, TEXT is same as CLOB. What ever limitations user guide mentions for CLOB is applicable to TEXT types.

Unlike typical datatypes, CLOB and TEXT need not store data inline to the record, instead the contents can be stored in a separate file and there will be pointer in the record. That is why direct path does not work for special types like CLOB/TEXT, BLOB in most of the databases.